# Server error in application - cannot find table 0

Tags: asp.net, deployment

While deploying an ASP.NET application in IIS 7, im getting error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

```
 Source Error: 
    Line 46:             dsDesignation= GetChartData("select * from LHSDesignation");
    Line 47: 
    Line 48:             if (dsDesignation != null && dsDesignation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    Line 49:             {
    Line 50:                 foreach (DataRow dr in dsDesignation.Tables[0].Rows)


    Source File: D:\Raji\LHS\LHS\Chart.aspx.cs    Line: 48 

Stack Trace: 

[IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.]
   System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) +95
   LHS.Chart.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Raji\LHS\LHS\Chart.aspx.cs:48
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

And the code for Page load is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tmpDesignation = string.Empty;
            conString =Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conString"]);
            strDesignation = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Designation"]);
            conection = new SqlConnection(conString);

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserLogin"] != null)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$.prompt('Please login to Update Score')", true);
            }

            dsDesignation= GetChartData("select * from LHSDesignation");

            if (dsDesignation != null && dsDesignation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsDesignation.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    dnDesignatin.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["DesignationName"]), Convert.ToString(dr["TargetScore"]));
                }
            }
```

Please help me in resolving this error
What need to be done to run in IIS 7?

Comment: check the result of your query "select * from LHSDesignation". dsDesignation maybe be empty.

Comment: its not empty, I am having values in that table

Comment: There can be many reasons to get an empty dataset. Check your connection strings. Log errors.

Comment: Are you using a `try catch` in `GetChartData`? Seems that is hiding your actual error.

Comment: yes.. im using try catch in Getchartdata. What should i do now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able run the application successfully. I did the following:

1. Created new login "IIS APPPOOL\LHS" in SQL SERVER
2. Created a folder named "TempImageFiles" in C:
   Then this ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

In Application Pool Enable 32 Bit Application it was resolved my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).